# Copy all contents of a directory and change names of the existing contents

Tags: c#, directory

a beginner here. I'm trying to copy all the contents from one folder to another. 
Let's say, the initial folder is called *inputDir*, and the one I'm copying the files to is called *outputDir*. The thing is, the *outputDir* already contains some files, and they're all named just like the files in *inputDir*. It all looks quite like this:

```
- inputDir
 * hit0.png
 * hit100.png
 * hit300.png

- outputDir
 * hit0.png
 * hit100.png
 * hit300.png
```

What I'm trying to do is to first rename all the files inside *outputDir* so that they all contain the characters 'bak' at they end of their names just before their extension and then copy all the files from *inputDir* to *outputDir*. In short, I want it to look like this:

```
- inputDir
 * hit0.png
 * hit100.png
 * hit300.png

- outputDir
 * hit0.png
 * hit0bak.png
 * hit100.png
 * hit100bak.png
 * hit300.png
 * hit300bak.png
```

So far I've tried doing it separately for each file, and it works fine; however, writing the very same code for, say, 20 more files is a lot of monotonous work, so I'd love to know if there's any faster way to do it in C# (yes, I need it done in C#, since the program does more than I wrote down here, but I've already covered everything else).
Thank you in advance for any help.

That's what I've tried so far:

```
if (File.Exists(outputDir + "\\" + "hit0.png"))
                {                    
                    File.Move(outputDir + "\\" + "hit0.png", outputDir + "\\" + "hit0bak.png");
                    File.Move(outputDir + "\\" + "hit100.png", outputDir + "\\" + "hit100bak.png");
                    File.Move(outputDir + "\\" + "hit300.png", outputDir + "\\" + "hit300bak.png");
                }
           File.Copy(inputDir + "\\" + "hit0.png", outputDir + "\\" + "hit0.png");
           File.Copy(inputDir + "\\" + "hit100.png", outputDir + "\\" + "hit100.png");
           File.Copy(inputDir + "\\" + "hit300.png", outputDir + "\\" + "hit100.png");
```

Comment: This is the description of your task. What is your question? Can you show what you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
        var sourcePath = @"c:\source\path";
        var destPath = @"c:\dest\path";

        var sourceDirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);

        foreach (var sourceFileInfo in sourceDirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(destPath, sourceFileInfo.Name)))
            {
                var bakName = sourceFileInfo.Name.Replace(".", "bak.");

                File.Move(Path.Combine(destPath, sourceFileInfo.Name),
                    Path.Combine(destPath, bakName));
            }

            File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourcePath, sourceFileInfo.Name),
                Path.Combine(destPath, sourceFileInfo.Name));
        }
```

(caveat - only works for filenames with one '.' in them)

Comment: That pretty much solved everything I wanted. Thank you very much.